# Как сделать анимацию 3d поворот куба на одну сторону при наведении мышкой только на css?

Tags: css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Как сделать анимацию 3d поворот куба на одну сторону при наведении мышкой только на css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  perspective: 500px;
  perspective-origin: center center;
}

.container {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 2px dotted white;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;  
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 2px dotted white;
}

.container:before {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

.container:after {
  transform: rotatey(90deg);
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-5em);
  background: orange;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(5em);
  background: gold;
}

.top {
  transform: translateY(-5em) rotateX(90deg);
  background: skyblue;
}

.bottom {
  transform: translateY(5em) rotateX(90deg);
  background: steelblue;
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-5em) rotateY(90deg);
  background: lightgreen;
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(5em) rotateY(90deg);
  background: yellowgreen;
}

.container:hover{
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="back side"></div>
  <div class="left side"></div>
  <div class="right side"></div>
  <div class="top side"></div>
  <div class="bottom side"></div>
  <div class="front side"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/vavik96/pen/WbqPRr?editors=1100

```css
    .wrap {
  margin-top: 150px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.cube {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube > div {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: #000;
  border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.front {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.right {
  transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) translateY(-100px);
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(270deg) translateY(100px);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.cube {
  animation: rotate 20s infinite linear;
}







.wrap:hover .front {
  transform: translateZ(200px);
}

.wrap:hover .back {
  transform: translateZ(-200px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.wrap:hover .right {
  transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateZ(100px) translateX(100px);
}

.wrap:hover .left {
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(100px) translateX(-100px);
}

.wrap:hover .top {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) translateZ(100px) translateY(-100px);
}

.wrap:hover .bottom {
  transform: rotateX(270deg) translateZ(100px) translateY(100px);
}




.cube > div {
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="front">
      Front side
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      Back side
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      Top side
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      Bottom side
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      Left side
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Right side
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS тоже прямо в ответ добавьте, пожалуйста. Спасибо.